# How to rename files when using 7zip for recursive extract

Tags: batch-file, recursion, extract, rename, 7zip

I have about 120,000 zip files that I am using the following command to extract:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %a in (`DIR /s /b *.zip`) do 7z.exe e %a
```

It extracts the contents of the files just fine but I created the zip files with a naming system and was wondering how to be able to apply the name of the zip file to the files within each zip.

For example

```
DR80005.zip contains Moo_Cow_Serenade.pdf
I'd like it to extract as DR80005.pdf
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a batch-based solution:

1. Do the same loop you have but redirect the (7z) extraction to another folder/directory
2. "extract" the name of the zip file to a variable
3. list the contents of what is in the extraction directory (the last extracted file) and rename/move it (with the name of the zip file you have stored in 2. and the same extension) to the final folder/directory

Just make sure the extraction folder/directory is empty to start with.

EDIT: Here is the code (already "optimized", from the above pseudo-code), for completion:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%a in (`DIR /s /b *.7z`) do ( 
   7za.exe e %%a -otempfolder
   ren tempfolder\*.* %%~na.*
   move tempfolder\*.* finalfolder
)
```

Notes: `tempfolder` is the temporary folder (needs to exist and be empty, prior to execution). In much the same way `finalfolder` is where all the extracted files will end up, with the new name.
Plus. This code assumes the zip files only have one compressed file inside.
Also. `7za.exe` is the command-line executable (of 7zip) .